# PCF: Creating an Organization

Tags: cloud-foundry, organization

I am logged in with a new account into https://console.run.pivotal.io; whereas it is not staying on the create an organization page; being redirected to https://console.run.pivotal.io/pws/users/new. Anyone has ideas why it is not switching to https://console.run.pivotal.io/organization/new?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer service question about a website.

Answer (score 2):

PWS took its final bow and left the stage back in Jan'21. You are no longer allowed to create org or use PWS anymore. For reference see this article:

https://blog.run.pivotal.io/pivotal-web-services-end-of-availability-announcement-and-timeline/

Comment: How do we go with managing PCF, are there alternatives to create organization via pcf cli?

Comment: May be look to migrate to one of certified providers: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/certified-platforms/

Comment: Hi @Hussain, If it helped, can you please accept the answer..

Comment: I would give a try with cfdev.